# Python - Code returns dates but when added to list the format changes

Tags: python, pandas, list, date, append

I am trying to create a list of dates to add to a Pandas dataframe as a new column using ...

```
df['Surveys_Last_Week'] = list
```

I have done this before without issues. However, with the code below I get the dates returned in the format I want but when I add them to a list the format changes and they become prefixed with datetime.date

```
2022-05-14
2022-07-09
2022-03-05
2022-03-12

[datetime.date(2022, 5, 14), datetime.date(2022, 7, 9), datetime.date(2022, 3, 5), datetime.date(2022, 3, 12)]
```

How can I get the dates into a list in the format that they return in?

The code I am using is as follows ...

```
today = datetime.date.today()

completion_list_80 = []

for value in df.Weeks_to_80pc:
    if value == float('inf'):
        pass
    else:
        remaining_weeks = datetime.timedelta(weeks=value)
        projected_completion = today + remaining_weeks
        print(projected_completion)
        completion_list_80.append(projected_completion)
                                     
print(completion_list_80)
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To convert the list of `datetime.date` objects to a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` column using NumPy's `datetime64` dtype, you can wrap `pandas.to_datetime()` around your list when you insert it into your DataFrame:

```
df['Surveys_Last_Week'] = pd.to_datetime(completion_list_80)
```

Alternatively, to convert the `datetime.date` objects to their `yyy-mm-dd` string representations, you can format them with `strftime` as you append them to the list (however, I would recommend sticking to pandas' builtin `DatetimeIndex` support):

```
completion_list_80.append(projected_completion.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```